# Extension's bracket pair colorization didn't work when opening vscode normally

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, color-scheme

I created a color scheme extension locally and I changed the bracket pair colorization settings.

```
"editorBracketHighlight.foreground1": "#3fb345",
...
"editorBracketHighlight.foreground6": "#c0be2a",
```

Debugging the extension works fine, the bracket color gets changed. But, when I open vscode normally, the bracket pair reverts to vscode's default! What am I doing wrong?

I have tried reloading the extension, but it doesn't work.

Comment: have you installed the extension and selected that theme

Comment: Of course, all of the color works except for the bracket. The bracket color is the same as vscode's default.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be a very stupid mistake. I have opened the wrong folder. Sorry.